# Append value to input field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append, hidden

I have a small form with three fields and I can submit that form choose different options next time. I am submitting this form with ajax call.

Now on form submit I want to post all the selected options. For this, I have created a hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedproduct[]" id="sel-product">
```

and ajax success method am appending value like

```
 $('#sel-product').val(element.product);
```

But here I am getting only one value instead of an array. How can I append all the values to the field?

Comment: Where did you get the element.product object? can you show us the structure of the element data.

Comment: in ajax response $(data.success).each(function( index, element  ) {$('#sel-product').val(element.product);});

Comment: That won't work. The input element will just be filled with the value of the last element of your array. You need to push the element.product in a temporary array variable then put the temp array on the input value.

Comment: But when I send ajax call again temp array getting reset and I have only one value :(

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the product fields with class ".element_product".

```
//init the array products
arrp=[];


//loop the elements
    $('.element_product').each( function () 
      {
            arrp.push( $(this).val() );
      });

//Pass the array to field
$('#sel-product').val(arrp);
```

Comment: You don't close your each loop

Comment: it still overwriting previous values

Comment: Store the previous values in an array and push arrp to array with previous values. Join them in input.

Comment: It still not working. Could you please whats wrong here [arrp=[]
                            temp =[];
                            temp = element. product;
                            $('.selectedMet').each( function ()
                            {
                                arrp.push(temp);
                            });

                            $('#sel-product').val(arrp);]

Comment: You are looping `element.product` (as `temp`) in the array without passing the values of inputs